# Thinkpad not working with docking station

Tags: thinkpad, dock

I have a Lenovo Thinkpad and a Lenovo dock station....everything was working well until last night. Now the second screen will not mirror the PC screen and when I close the PC screen the Monitor screen also goes blank. I cannot see anything weird in the log apart from 4 of these meaningless 00/00 lines coloured red over the last 24 hours or so...

Jan 30 15:19:27 joan--Carbon kernel: [   39.505511] ---[ end trace c293571185b7f534 ]---

\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\0

Jan 30 15:20:44 joan--Carbon systemd-modules-load[295]: Inserted module 'lp'

I can only presume that something has been corrupted....but what? Suggestions very much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Today I had the same problem as you. There is a bug in kernel 4.15.0-44. See here: 
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1813765

To downgrade the kernel to 4.15.0-43 please follow instructions from https://itsfoss.com/upgrade-linux-kernel-ubuntu/

Comment: Thank you so much....I really appreciate your help!